# TCL RegExp IP exceptions

Tags: tcl

I have the following TCl regexp to extract an exact IP from a line:

```
set ip [regexp -all -inline {((([2][5][0-5]|([2][0-4]|[1][0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9])\.){3})([2][5][0-5]|([2][0-4]|[1][0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9])} $ip_text]
```

I'm using it to analyze a log file, and it works fine, except it's also extracting the domain name IP portion when the domain name also contains an IP format (but usually in reverse), which I don't wan't

eg when `ip_text = Log File 61.140.142.192 - 2012-06-16, 192.142.140.61.broad.gz.gd.dynamic.163data.com.cn, CHN, 1`

I get 61.140.142.192 & 192.142.140.61 but only **61.140.142.192** is legit.

and when `ip_text = Entry "61.140.170.118" resolved from 118.170.140.61.broad.gz.gd.dynamic.163data.com.cn, and 61.140.185.45 verified.`

I get 61.140.170.118, 118.170.140.61 & 164.111.111.34 but only **61.140.170.118** & **61.140.185.45** are legit.

Is there a way to make the regexpr exclude IP's that have a domain name character after it? ie exclude `<IP><dot>` or `<IP><dash>` or `<IP><any alpha/numeric character>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead constraint on the end of that RE. Those are written as `(?!\.|\d)` in this case, which matches when the next character is *not* a `.` or a digit (it also matches at the end of the string, when there's no next character at all). With complicated regular expressions it's often easier to save them in a variable (often global) since that effectively lets you name the RE.

```
set IPAddrRE {(((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9])\.){3})(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9])(?!\.|\d)}
set ip [regexp -all -inline $IPAddrRE $ip_text]
```

The reason you need to prevent the follower being a digit? Without that, the RE can stop matching one character earlier, allowing it to pick `192.142.140.6` out of your sample text as well as the value you actually want.

---

You should consider using non-capturing grouping for this task. Replacing `(…)` with `(?:…)` will allow the RE engine to use a more efficient matcher internally. On a lot of text, this will make a substantial difference. For example, with this version:

```
set IPAddrRE {(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9])(?!\.|\d)}
```

I see that the time to execute is about half what the version I listed in the first part of this answer is (and about 40% of what your original version required). However, it produces different results — none of the bits that you probably don't require — so you'll need to adapt other code too:

```
% set ip [regexp -all -inline $IPAddrRE $ip_text]
61.140.142.192
```

Comment: It seems to be working correctly for accurate extraction & multiple IPs now. I also implemented ?:, adjusted the coding and global variabled it. You were correct, currently don't need the extra 'plus one element for each subexpression' in the regular expression, and yep it saved average 41% overall :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's often a good idea to dumb down your regular expressions instead of trying to make them smarter.

```
lmap candidate [regexp -inline -all {[\d.]+} $txt] {
    if {[llength [split $candidate .]] == 4} {
        set candidate
    } else {
        continue
    }
}
```

will pick out the exact three numbers you wanted from your text.

Documentation: [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [lmap](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570) replacement, [Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I was using (?:\d+\.){3}\d+ before, but due to the wide variation of the log files data, it was giving me a lot of false postives :( There's also a lot of data (its network traffic), so speed is somewhat important...

Comment: @jkeys: well, that regular expression is still a lot more complicated that it needs to be. As for speed, my solution is twice as fast as Donal's. The speed advantage might be reduced if other kinds of false positives are accounted for: I only dealt with the ones you mentioned.

Comment: A small concession to the magic of regular expression matching: setting the regex to `[\d.]{7,}` makes the solution a bit faster, putting it at 33% of the wholly regex solution (a lot of the candidates were really short strings that couldn't possibly be ip numbers).

Comment: I think that still gives false positives :( with examples like:

"122.177.80.76    # 2015-06-09, abts-north-dynamic-076.80.177.122.airtelbroadband.in, IND, 1" FALSE IP: 076.80.177.122 & 
"186.151.61.62    # 2016-05-23, "62.61.151.186.static.intelnet.net.gt, GTM, 1" FALSE IP: 62.61.151.186

Comment: @jkeys: I can't reproduce that. When I cut and paste your texts from your comment and the code from my example, none of those false ips are in the result. Are you sure you used the exact code I posted?

Comment: set data "{121.25.247.249    # 2016-01-13, 249.247.025.121.broad.pt.fj.dynamic.163data.com.cn, CHN, 1} {121.205.248.3    # 2014-11-23, 3.248.205.121.broad.pt.fj.dynamic.163data.com.cn, CHN, 1}"; puts [regexp -all -inline {[\d.]{7,}} $data]; ###121.25.247.249 249.247.025.121. 121.205.248.3 3.248.205.121.###

Comment: set data "{122.177.80.76 # 2015-06-09, abts-north-dynamic-076.80.177.122.airtelbroadband.in, IND, 1} {186.151.61.62 # 2016-05-23, 62.61.151.186.static.intelnet.net.gt, GTM, 1}"; puts [regexp -all -inline {[\d.]{7,}} $data]; ###122.177.80.76 076.80.177.122. 186.151.61.62 62.61.151.186.###

Comment: @jkeys: use the code in my answer (`lmap ...`) with the regex set to either `[\d.]+` (simpler) or `[\d.]{7,}` (faster).